# Ask how to use the extended_image package in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

everyone here.
I have a question about the extended_image package.

Extended_image was installed for cache. I found that the default value for cache is true. If I use ExtendedImage.network, does it automatically cache?

And is there a way to use the cache image or to confirm that the cache image is used?

Please give us a lot of guidance.

1. How to cache network image when using extended_image package
2. How to use cache image
3. How to check that the current load image is a cache image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `ExtendedImage.network` automatically stores loaded images to cache using the image URL as the key, you can set the `cache` parameter to false if you want to disable this behavior.

Also if you want to set your own cache key, you can use the `cacheKey` property.